# Customized email Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email-validation

I am using Javascript email validation using regular expression.

I am using the below function

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
     var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

It works fine for various email validation scenario. Let say for example

```
validateEmail('m@s'); // return false
```

But if I try to validate something like

```
validateEmail('m@com.com'); // return true
```

Which is true as per the regular expression.

What I need is, it will also validate that text "com" before and after ".", such a that both the texts should not be the same.

Any help will be appreciated... :)

Comment: ..but `com.com` is a real website?

Comment: Why? `com.com` is a real domain which people could have an email account at.

Comment: As are things like http://info.info/

Comment: Its just a scenario, it can be any domain text say "xyz@gmail.gmail" or whatever the same text.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I like me.me and be.be (the latter redirects to becomeviking.com)

Comment: Do you need that validation using regex?

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about JS email validation... Basic validation is enough - if you need really valid email address from user - force registration/login via email...

Comment: Yeah, but how can we achieve this through js code?

Comment: Can we achieve this through regular expression?

Comment: `"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org` is a valid email address, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: Thanks, everyone for sharing your views :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some cosmetic changes in above code and it works.. :)

Below is the changed function in which valid email is rechecked for the text after "@" but before and after the "."

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
   var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;  
     if(re.test(email)){   
       var afteratRate = email.substr(email.indexOf("@") + 1); 
       var spmail = afteratRate.split(".");
       if(spmail[0] === spmail[1]){
           return false;
        }
    }
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Then test for below scenarios

```
validateEmail('m@.com'); // gives false
validateEmail('m@s.com'); // gives true
validateEmail('test@gmail.com'); // gives true
validateEmail('test@com.com'); // gives false
```